# Is there a way to Justify the text on R Markdown?

Tags: r

I am using R Studio Cloud and knitting it to a word document through R Markdown. I would like to justify the text. I need an especific code or I can use any feature from R Studio?

Comment: I would assume that text alignment would be handled with the reference document. Perhaps start [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClaudiaDL,
I've included a video and some articles I found on RStudio regarding how to setup a refrence docx for the styles you'd like to use in your RMarkdown document when it outputs to a Word document.

Here is a video on how to set it up: https://vimeo.com/110804387

And here are two more articles on how to do it.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html

Comment: Thank you! It's been so useful!